# SQL Server 2008 - Add Windows Account After Deleting Default User

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

This is rather embarrassing, but I accidentally deleted my Windows account from the list of SQL Server 2008 users and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to re-add myself now that I don't have login privileges.

The server is running on my machine and the only other Windows users with access are IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE and SYSTEM. Is there anything I can do short of re-installing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I also recently deleted my windows account from my local development 2008 server. I was able to use SQL server's Single User Mode to recreate my login and add it to the sysadmin role. It took just a few minutes, and I didn't have to admit my terrible error to anyone.

From MSDN:

> Starting SQL Server in single-user mode enables any member of the
>   computer's local Administrators group to connect to the instance of SQL
>   Server as a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

Here's how I reinstated myself:

1. Exit out of SSMS
2. Stop any SQL related services. I had to stop Reporting Services. Other SQL services such as SQL Agent will also use up your one, valuable connection.
3. Stop the SQL service
4. Start the SQL service with the extra parameter `-m`. This will put the SQL into Single User Mode. This means that SQL will only accept one connection.
5. Use `sqlcmd` to connect to your server with the `-E` trusted connection option. SQL will accept you into the `sysadmin` role if you're a local administrator.
6. In the interactive session, create your login and add to the `sysadmins` role.

   ```
   USE master
   GO
   CREATE LOGIN [domain\username] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Master]
   GO
   EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame=N'domain\username', @rolename=N'sysadmin'
   GO
   ```
7. Stop the SQL service, remove the `-m` parameter and restart the service. You should now be able to go back into SSMS and continue using the server normally.

If you get the message:

> Login failed for user 'domain\username'. Reason: Server is in single user
>   mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.

Then there is something using your single connection. You'll need to find that service or connection and stop it before you can log in. Check SQL Agent, SQL Reporting Services, SQL Analysis Services etc.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.  To start and stop the service from the command line I found this [technet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd421654.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Updated to preferred answer as blog link in original answer is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, this wasn't too hard to fix (not that it should have been hard...)!

[<strike>This blog post</strike>](http://deepakrangarajan.blogspot.com/2008/01/forgot-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005.html) explains the steps for starting SQL Server in Single User Mode, which (for some reason) allowed me to login as my Windows administrator account, add the account to the user list (with CREATE LOGIN), enable the SA user and set its password to something I actually knew, and finally login as SA and give the Windows account sysadmin privileges.

**Edit 07/05/13:** [Try this link instead](http://web.archive.org/web/20110924031857/http://deepakrangarajan.blogspot.com/2008/01/forgot-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005.html).

Answer (score 0):

Often SQL Server is installed so that any any local administrator is a SQL Server `sysadmin`.

If this is your case you can run Management Studio as administrator and then add any other windows user as a login in the Security section.

This solution worked for me.